# my chilli plants have spots and holes appearing on them

Tags: chili

I have white spots which turn brown and in some cases holes form and the leaf withers and falls off eventually. I haven’t had any issue with fruiting, there has been plenty. I water once every one or two days depending on weather. I have fertilized twice with miracle grow in the 10 weeks I have been growing the plants. Do you have any idea what causes this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like bacterial leaf spot. This is the most common and most deadly disease of peppers and tomatoes. You can read more about treatment options on the internet. Avoid splashing water from the ground onto the leaves or getting leaves wet when watering plants.